# HTML Video autoplay is not working on iphones

Tags: html, html5-video, shopify, autoplay

```
  <video width="100%" playsinline preload="metadata" style="object-fit: cover;height:100%" muted="true" autoplay="true"> 
   <source src="{{video_url}}" type="video/mp4"/>
        </video>
```

On a Shopify site, I have a section with Video Background without audio (also muted). `playsinline` attribute was added. 
Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Is the device in low power mode? Because if so it won't autoplay video.

Comment: **(1)** Does **console** show any errors like "autoplay not allowed" or similar? **(2)** Try giving `width="100%"` a real number like 500 as `width="500"` **(3)** Try forcing play through Javascript. Make sure you give the `<video>` tag an ID to access it by code. Listen for a "load" event for the page `addEventListener("load", on_page_Ready );` where **on_page_Ready** is a function that tells video to play.

Comment: It worked after changing the width number. Thank you